# Searching files - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nspredicate

I am trying to search for a file. This returns 0 results. Does anyone know why?

```
NSMetadataQuery *q = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kMDItemFSName == %@", @"test123456.png"];  
[q setPredicate:predicate];

[q startQuery];
while ([q isGathering]) {
    NSLog(@"%lu", [q resultCount]);
}

[q stopQuery];
```

### update

```
NSMetadataQuery *q = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kMDItemFSName == %@", @"test123456.png"];  
    [q setPredicate:predicate];

    [q startQuery];
    NSLog(@"%lu", [q resultCount]);

    [q stopQuery];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kMDItemSFName == %@", @"test123456.png"];
```

If you copied that exactly from your code, methinks `kMDItemSFName` should be `kMDItemFSName`. ;-)

Are you using the foundation tool template, or a full application that will have a run loop?

Basically, I believe `MDMetadataQuery` is designed to be run asynchronously, where you start the query and will be notified of the results when the query has finished.

From [Introduction to Spotlight Query Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/SpotlightQuery.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001843-BBCFBCAG):

> For applications that need to create
>   queries and interact with the results
>   there are two APIs available. The
>   Spotlight metadata framework provides
>   a low-level query API, `MDQuery`, that
>   allows an application to search for
>   files based on metadata values.
>   `MDQuery` is completely configurable,
>   *allowing you to run synchronous and
>   asynchronous queries* and provides
>   fine-grain control of the frequency of
>   results batching.
>
> The Cocoa frameworks's `NSMetadataQuery`
>   class provides a high-level
>   Objective-C interface to the `MDQuery`
>   API. This class allows you to
>   construct queries using a subset of
>   the `NSPredicate` classes, *and execute
>   the queries asynchronously*.
>   `NSMetadataQuery` supports Cocoa
>   bindings, allowing you to display the
>   results without writing any
>   significant amount of glue code. As
>   well, `NSMetadataQuery` allows an
>   application to specify the grouping of
>   the results into multiple
>   subcategories. *`NSMetadataQuery` does
>   not support synchronous queries* and
>   provides minimal update notifications
>   as data is collected.

See [Technical Note TN2192 Querying Metadata With Spotlight](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2192/_index.html).

Comment: I still get 0 results though.

Comment: Aftering adding CoreServices.framework, I still get 0 results.

Comment: I am updating my question without the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since NSMetadataQuery works asynchronously the run loop needs to reached to get results. You can set a delegate or register a notification that gets called when results are found or as soon as there are updates.

I don't find that mentioned in the Mac documentation but in the iOS 5 documentation they explicitly state that. Maybe it's not true for OS X? But you should give it a try.

"The query sends notifications as the results are returned in batches. The query sends the application a notification when the initial results gathering phase has completed." (found in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryingMetadata.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001848-CJBEJBHH)

Answer (score 0):

declare NSMetaDataQuery q in .h file and check resultCount on receiving NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification.

```
 someFunction
        {

           [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                             selector:@selector(initalGatherComplete:)
                                                              name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification
                                                               object:metadataSearch];

                q = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
                NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kMDItemFSName == %@", @"test123456.png"];  
                [q setPredicate:predicate];

                [q startQuery];

        }


            - (void)initalGatherComplete:sender;
            {
                [q stopQuery];

                NSLog(@"%lu",[q resultCount]);

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                                name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification
                                                              object:metadataSearch];

            }
```